# Syntax error in MongoClient connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mlab

Here is what my server is telling me:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://<'yoda'>:<'yoda69'>@ds235778.mlab.com:35778/satr-wars-quotes', (err, client) => {
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Here is the code:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://<'yoda'>:<'yoda69'>@ds235778.mlab.com:35778/satr-wars-quotes', (err, client) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  db = client.db('satr-wars-quotes')
  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3000')
  })
})
```

I just don't see where this syntax error is being made.

Answer (score 2):

What are `yoda` and `yoda69`? Are they variable names, or literal strings?

If they are variable names, you need to either append them to the string using the `+` operator, or use ES6 template strings to interpolate their values into the larger string:

```
'mongodb://<' + yoda + '>:<' + yoda69 + '>@ds235778.mlab.com:35778/satr-wars-quotes'
```

or

```
`mongodb://<${yoda}>:<${yoda69}>@ds235778.mlab.com:35778/satr-wars-quotes`
```

If they are the literal strings, see scniro's answer.

Comment: @scniro Whoops, this was carelessness on my part to not check for posted answers before I posted mine (there wasn't an answer when I started answering). I'll edit out the part about using double quotes.

Comment: so this a URL I made with mLab and that is the username and user password I am trying to connect MongoClient to in my project. I don't think I even really need those quotes in the tags for the username and user password to be honest, but when they aren't there, I get this error when I try to run the server: Error: Username contains an illegal unescaped character. Any idea what that is telling me?

Comment: @kalex I'm fairly certain the correct format is `mongodb://username:password@...` (without the quotes or `<`/`>`).

Comment: @tverghis you're right, I misunderstood the syntax from mlab. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have single quotes in a singly-quoted string. I'd suggest [escaping them](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/quotesin.htm), or double quote your string, with singles on the inside (or the inverse). Observe the following...

```
"mongodb://<'yoda'>:<'yoda69'>@ds235778.mlab.com:35778/satr-wars-quotes"
```

As far as if your connection string is correct, I am unsure, but this fixes your immediate syntax error.